# Python retrieve DayOfWeek as integer

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to get the day of the week as integer.

If i use the following for day of the month `mydate.day` i would like to do the same for weekday.

i tried `mydate.weekday` but this does not give me the integer (0 for sunday to 6 for saturday).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using some library or did you write this class yourself? If the latter, can we see how you defined your class?

Comment: import datetime // mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2005-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Can you show us that `mydate.weekday()` returns? Assuming `mydate` is a `datetime.datetime` then it should work... Ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday

Comment: what package is mydate from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), use [`datetime.datetime.weekday` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday):

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 24, 22, 47, 3, 80000)
>>> d.weekday()  # Monday
0
>>> (d.weekday() + 1) % 7
1
```

You need to (... + 1) % 7 because the method return 0 for Monday, 6 for Sunday.

**UPDATE**

You can also use [`datetime.datetime.isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) which return 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday.

```
>>> d.isoweekday() % 7
1
```

Comment: You might also find https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday useful - it gives Monday=1, ..., Sunday=7.

Comment: i was missing the () -- mydate.weekday has to be mydate.weekday() thank you, will accept in few minutes

Comment: @TomDalton, Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer to include the `isoweekday`.

Comment: @phicon, Could you update your question? `0 for sunday to 6 for monday` does not make sense for me. (Did you mean 6 for Saturday?)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little confused by your wording:

> (0 for sunday to 6 for monday)  # how would Monday be 6?

But I wonder if you want the [`isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> d.isoweekday()
1                                 # Monday
```

**Edit**:

In light of your desire for Sunday to be 0, you should go with [falsetru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27106387/1775603) (after the edit):

```
>>> d.isoweekday() % 7
```

Or simply convert Sunday to 0 elsewhere in your code.

Comment: sorry, i meant monday 1 and saturday 6. My bad

Comment: @phicon No worries. Glad you found your answer. falsetru's answer is a good one (and got a +1 from me).

Answer (score 1):

Python uses 0 for Monday. See the [weekday](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) documentation.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 23)
print now
print now.weekday()
```

This is a Sunday, so prints this:

```
2014-11-23 00:00:00
6
```

This is an example of a Monday:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now
print now.weekday()
```

This is a Monday so prints this:

```
2014-11-24 07:47:19.827000
0
```